# Скрипт на JS с выводом результата

Tags: javascript

необычная просьба подсказать скрипт, который принимает с клавиатуры целое положительное число и выводит его на экран в «полном виде»: например, для числа 134 чтоб смотрелось как 100+30+4. Пытался калякать - неудачно, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Приложите свои каляки.

Comment: Приведите пример своего решения, и мы подскажем, в чем ваша ошибка и как ее устранить.
Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А ведь ничего сложного.

- Получаем число как строку.
- Делаем массив из каждой цифры.
- Лепим в конец нужное нам количество нулей (в нашем случае `n.length - i - 1`, т.е. сначала идут сотни, потом десятки и тд.).
- Потом просто с помощью `join()` делаем строку, указывая `+`, как символ между элементами.

```js
const n = prompt('Enter number: ');

console.log([...n].map((e, i) => e + '0'.repeat(n.length - i - 1)).join `+`);
```

UPD:

Добавил удаление пустых нулей и перевод числа с экспоненциальной записи.

```js
const n = +prompt('Enter number: ')+''; // либо String(+prompt())

console.log([...n].map((e, i) => e + '0'.repeat(n.length - i - 1)).join `+`.replace(/\+[0]+/g, ''));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122631/discussion-on-answer-by-entithat---js---).